# Does Sorcerous Blade Channeling grant the weapon's proficiency bonus?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, sorcerer

The Sorcerous Blade Channeling feat says:

> When you use any ranged sorcerer attack power through a dagger, you can use the power as a melee attack. If you do so, the power’s range equals your melee reach.

Does the player get the dagger's +3 proficiency bonus? I would prefer an official reference if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You apply the weapon proficiency bonus only if the Sorcerer attack power has the "weapon" keyword.**

From the [Bonus definition](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=536) on DDI:

> **Proficiency Bonus:** Gained from proficiency with a weapon, this bonus applies to attack rolls with that weapon. An adventurer gains the proficiency bonus only when wielding the weapon and using powers that have the weapon keyword.

Looks like there are currently 8 Sorcerer powers that have the weapon keyword, all in Dragon 379 and 390.  Most are already Melee weapon attacks so they would not benefit overmuch from the Sorcerous Blade Channeling feat.

Comment: In fact, of the 6 Sorcerer Attack powers I can find with the Weapon keyword, only **one** is not already a Melee attack... and that one is a Close blast. Considering the various ways to avoid provoking attacks with a ranged attack, Sorcerous Blade Channeling seems like a speedbump feat for the 5 other feats that require it.

Answer (score -4):

You should, since melee attacks have the "weapon" keyword, and you would have the dagger to use already as an implement for your ranged attacks.

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. Melee attacks do *NOT* automatically have the Weapon keyword. If a power does not already have the Weapon keyword (and very few sorcerer powers do), then turning it into a melee attack with Sorcerous Blade Channeling will **not** give it the Weapon keyword.